# ansible + is it possible to locate ansible under some folder

Tags: rhel, software-installation, ansible, pip

the usual way to install the ansible is by rpm's and pip installation
some times this make conflicts and problem of dependencies

is it possible to locate ansible under folder with all binaries without the usual way of installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use virtualenv and pip to install ansible [as described in this document by F5](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/orchestration/ansible/devel/usage/virtualenv.html), just ignore the F5-specific ansible module info at the end.

Comment: hi Mike do you work at F5?